# Getting User location lat lng with API 22

Tags: android, geolocation

Trying something as simple as the following code, does not seem to work:

I always get in the logs "No Location :("

Am I missing something?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location != null){
        Log.i("Location","Location achieved");
    }else{
        Log.i("Location","No location :(");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is no last known location?

Comment: Do you Want Complete code?

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` will return `null` if there is no cached location. Hence, your behavior is perfectly normal. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running an emulator, make sure to send an location event from the emulator settings. Nevertheless, `getLastKnownLocation` can always return `null`. You could use `LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates` to listen to any location changes instead.

Comment: Thanks that did the work. Those settings are located on the right of the phone emulator. The nav bar on the right at the icon is at the bottom with three points.

Answer (score 2):

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

in onCreate():

```
      new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
         .addApi(LocationServices.API)
         .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
         .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
         .build()
```

Total code in Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
         @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            updateUI();
        }

        private void updateUI() {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
        }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}
    }
```

To Stop receiving updates:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}

protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);
}
```